# Expose a website hosted on a server with a dynamicip through a subdomain

Tags: dns, iis, iis-7, dynamic-ip, cname

This is what I'm trying to do:

Got a Windows Server 2008 R2 instance at home (dynamic ip), and want to expose one or more of its websites (IIS 7.5). Here's what I think I should be doing, and I'm not sure about some of the steps:

1. Obviously setup a forwarding rule on my router so that any HTTP:80 requests are forwarded to the Win2k8 server. Already did this. Is there any benefit to setting the server to be the DMZ machine?
2. Since it has a dynamic ip, I will need to install a dyanmic dns update client, probably no-ip's.
3. I've got my domain hosted on winhost.com, and want to leave it there, but it has a DNS manager interface that allows me to create A, MX, CNAME and TXT records.

From what I've been reading, I could create a CNAME record for mysubdomain.mydomain.com and point it to my named dynamic ip, like mysubdomain.no-ip.com, and it should work

so, first question: am I on the right path with this?

second question: If I wanted to expose two different websites from the home server, using different domains (one being subdomain.mydomain.com and the other being www.domain2.com), when it comes to IIS, should I expose them both through the 80 port/binding, just with different domains (they allow you to type a domain name). If not, should they be different ports in the IIS website for domain2.com, and how could I still xpose it as www.domain2.com from the outside?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A lot of ISPs block inbound requests on TCP 80 to prevent people from hosting their own websites. Call them and make sure that they aren't doing that for you. They don't usually block TCP 443 though so using HTTPS instead of HTTP is an easy fix for this, but you'll probably want a valid SSL certificate rather than a self-signed one.

Comment: fair point Agrajag, so would it be possible to host the IIS website on say, port 8080, but still expose it as www.domain2.com? Like, is it possible to map a domain like domain2.com to mysubdomain.no-ip.com:8080?

Comment: the company I'm considering using (no-ip) apparently allows this (http://www.no-ip.com/support/ on #4), but i'm not sure if this can be achieved generally or they have special configuration rules. any ideas?